# VPS/Cloud configuration management automatization for small environments

Tags: configuration, virtual-machine, vps, cloud

What would be an appropriate tool/approach for configuration management of a relatively small number of VPS/VMs (1-5). Even though it's a small number I'm a big fan of "nuke 'n boot" in case of any problems and therefore need to be able to setup a new VPS with an existing configuration quickly (minutes).

Puppet, chef and the likes seem to be fairly oversized for that setup - apart from the fact that they aim to sell their enterprise version and the open source version is rather crippled. Open Source is a must criteria for me.

I currently manage most of this stuff manually by having copies of the relevant config files on dropbox or summaries in evernote, etc. Preferably I would like to use a tool that runs on a local Ubuntu server or so from which I could easily manage one to a few remote VPS or local VM instances.

Does anyone have experience with that topic and can recommend something? I consider chef and puppet oversized, etckeeper on the other hand is a bit too limited.

---

Edit:
A solution with Management UI would be preferred

---

I summarize the proposals from the comments here:

- [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) Open Source version without UI and limited features
- [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/) Open Source version with a bit less features
- [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) non UI, scripting or ruby
- [Foreman](http://theforeman.org) UI for Puppet, Chef

Comment: I think you may get better suggestions at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that community yet. On the other hand it's pretty linux specific so...

Comment: I am not sure of it. May be, you can take a look at this link. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software

Comment: Thanks, I found that page, too. I'm still hoping that someone with hands on experience in that matter might share his experience/approach to this specific question.

Comment: Capistrano is a good one to start with. http://capistranorb.com/

Comment: You should have a look into Foreman if UI is a hard requirement. It uses puppet or chef as a configuration backend. Also, puppet is opensource and features are same as enterprise version.

Comment: Ansible is my favorite as it's agentless.